# How to import Google Code issues into JIRA (or redmine)?

Tags: migration, google-code, issue-tracking

As Google Code doesn't support Git, I'm moving a Google Code hosted project to my own server. And change to use JIRA for issue tracking, because there is a Git plugin for JIRA. (I don't like the Git plugin for Trac, though) It's easy to convert SVN repository to Git, however, unfortunately, Google Code seems not able to export the issue database. So this question.

Comment: eh, Google Code [supports git](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ChoosingAVersionControlSystem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get issues out of the issue tracker in two ways:

1. There is a GData api: http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/IssueTrackerAPI
2. There is a "csv" link at the bottom of the issue list page.

For your needs, you probably want the GData API.

But, as mentioned by @Sathya, Google Code supports git.